# Paste last cell address of worksheet 1 in worksheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

```
lRow1 = Cells.Find(What:="0", _
After:=Range("A1"), _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
MatchCase:=False).Row
MsgBox "Last Row: " & lRow1
```

Instead of a msg box, i want the Cell address to be pasted in a different worksheet

Comment: `Worksheets("Worksheet2").Range("A1").Value = lRow1`.

Comment: Use `What:="*"`.

Comment: How can i get cell address of last row?

Comment: Instead of `.Row` use `.Address`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
Dim lRow1 As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = Activesheet

' Find last row
lRow1 = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Put the last address value to A1 cell of Sheet2
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value = "A" & lRow1
```